# Javascript get embedded youtube id

Tags: javascript, youtube, html-parsing

I have youtube videos embedded like so:

```
    <object height="25" width="610"><param name="movie" 
    value="http://www.youtube.com/v/GBApIkX0YN4&hl=en_US&color1=0xf4f4f4&color2=0xffffff&hd=0&fs=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer">
    </param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    </param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    </param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/GBApIkX0YN4&hl=en_US&color1=0xf4f4f4&color2=0xffffff&hd=0&fs=0" height="25" width="610" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always">
    </embed></object>
```

---

In the youtube example they use the below code to see when the players state changes.

```
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

    function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
    }
```

**When I put this into my page nothing happens whenI play pause the vid (I think it should be doing an alert saying what the state is.)**

I would like to get its id using javascript which is "GBApIkX0YN4" so that I can then use the youtube api and find out when the video has ended to call a javascript function.

1. Is there an easier way to tell when the video has ended?
2. If not, how would I get its ID?

I saw another person used

```
    youtubeID = v.attr('src').match(/youtube\.com.*?v[\/=](\w+)/)[1];
```

But I do not know how to find the url from the embed code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [Youtube Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) This can be enabled in your embed URLs by including `&enablejsapi=1` so your URLs will look like:

`http://www.youtube.com/v/GBApIkX0YN4&hl=en_US&color1=0xf4f4f4&color2=0xffffff&hd=0&fs=0&enablejsapi=1`

In order to call the player API methods, you must first get a reference to the player object you wish to control. this can be done by getting the  player object by calling getElementById() on the  or  tag.

You can then set the `onStateChange` event on the player object which will return a value depending on the state of the video. You will want to check the value is 0 which states the video has ended.

From the documentation:

```
This event is fired whenever the player's state changes. Possible values are unstarted (-1), ended (0), playing (1), paused (2), buffering (3), video cued (5). When the SWF is first loaded it will broadcast an unstarted (-1) event. When the video is cued and ready to play it will broadcast a video cued event (5).
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: getElementById() on the or tag. This is the part I'm not sure about

Comment: There is demo of the Yotube API and the 'on-state-change' feature being used to play videos in sequence on the lovelogic.net radio station. Just right click to view soure it's all done using javascript.

Comment: I updated the code I have. Could you tell me why its not working?